# Solution of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{a^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was doing some math problems when I got stuck at summing the series of the form

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{a^n}$$

where $x<1$ and $a$ is any positive integer.
Since $x^n>x^{a^n}$, the series converges by Comparison test. I tried everything I knew but I 
couldn't produce the solution.

Comment: Hello, since you're new here, please learn to input $\LaTeX$ codes for mathematical formulae, thanks!

Comment: Not **any** positive integer: $a=1$ is excluded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no closed-form solution.  Some facts about this are known: the series is called a "lacunary series", and has a natural boundary on the circle $|x|=1$ in the complex plane.